# Vcenter Virtual Appliance External SSO Server Setup

Tags: vmware, virtualization, vsphere

I have recently downloaded Vcenter 5.1 virtual appliance and deployed it as a virtual host on a ESXi host. Currently I am using the embedded SSO for user authentication and authorization, but as we already have an existing setup of LDAP server with samba PDC, is there some way to integrate VCenter appliance with the existing system ? In Vcenter configuration, external SSO requires an external lookup service URL with username and password. Any thoughts on possible solutions please ??

Answer (score 0):

[Add a vCenter Single Sign On Identity Source](http://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/topic/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-B23B1360-8838-4FF2-B074-71643C4CB040.html)